# Clean way to implement validation on non-crud routes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

How do you implement validation on NON-CRUD routes? For example, there is a route for browsing `recipes`. It accepts parameters `term` (for search), `sort`, `page` and so on.

What is the neatest way to do this in Rails?

The most straight-forward solution would be to validate all these things using the bunch of `if-else` expressions in the controller, but I'm looking for something more clean and easier for extension and maintinance.

I ended up with the following

```
class RequestValidation
  attr_reader :validators
  attr_reader :errors

  def initialize
    @validators = []
    @errors = []
  end

  def add_validator(validator)
    @validators << validator
  end

  def validate
    @validators.each do |validator|
      validator.validate
      @errors += validator.errors
    end
  end

  def valid?
    validate
    errors.empty?
  end

end
```

Example of validator class

```
  class SortValidator < Validator

    VALID_SORT_FIELD = [:created_at, :rate, :total_time]
    VALID_SORT_DIRECTIONS = [:asc, :desc]

    def validate
      return unless param

      valid = true
      begin
        sort = param.to_unsafe_h

        if sort.size == 1
          k = sort.keys[0].to_sym
          v = sort.values[0].to_sym
          valid = VALID_SORT_FIELD.include?(k) && VALID_SORT_DIRECTIONS.include?(v)
        else
          valid = false
        end
      rescue => ex
        valid = false
      end

      @errors << "Sort parameter invalid" unless valid
    end

    def is_valid?
      !errors.empty?
    end
  end
```

So, `RequestValidation` is like a builder / container class for all validators. And then, in the controller:

```
    validation = RequestValidation.new
    validation.add_validator(RecipesValidators::SortValidator.new(params[:sort]))

    validation.validate

    if validation.errors.empty?
```

This way, when new validation is required, we just need to create a new Validator class and add it to request validation.

Given that I took a pause from Rails for several years, there are doubts if this code is clean and neat and in accordance with Ruby principles.

Or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could just implement a, for example, `RecipeFilter` class the includes the [`ActiveModel::Validations`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html) module. That would allow you to use existing Rails validators or easily implement custom validation following default Rails conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here was never really a custom validator - instead you should create a class such as a model or form object to encapsulate the validations and data. Just because your action doesn't persist anything doesn't mean you can't use a model to represent data and buisness logic.

```
class RecipeSearch
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes

  attribute :query, :string
  attribute :sort_by, :string
  # ...

  validates :query, length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates :sort_by, in: ['newest', 'quickest', 'cheapest'] 
  # ...

  # @todo apply filters to Recipe and return collection
  def perform
     # ... 
  end
end
```

This lets you add validations and logic. And pass it to forms:

```
<%= form_with(model: local_assigns(:recipe_seach) || RecipeSearch.new) do |f| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Its also a misconception that searching can't be a part of CRUD. It is after all just Read with filters applied. If you really need a separate view from your normal index then by all means create a separate search action but its not really a neccissity.

```
class RecipesController
  def index
    @recipe_search = RecipeSearch.new(search_params)
    @recipes = @recipe_search.perform
  end

  private 

  def search_params
    params.fetch(:recipe_search, {})
          .permit(:query, :sort_by)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try this, it looks promising :)

Comment: Lust a small question. Would performing DB query (by filters on model) be violation of single responsibility principle here? Since we have the validation and structure logic and DB logic in the same class. I usually user Query classes for DB logic...

Comment: @aldm Yes, it could seen as a violation of the SRP - Rails models are pretty much a huge blatant violation of it though. You could very well extract the functionality of applying the filters as a database query into its own class. The main responsibility of the model here would be handling user input.

Comment: I would really prefer this solution in a Rails project over the struct approach used by @rewritten. ActiveModel has a lot of powerful stuff like mass assignment, typecasting, defaults, I18n etc. It avoids an additional dependency and introducing yet another DSL that maintainers will hate you for.

Comment: I agree with you. I ended up using this, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays I would go with putting some contract and strongly typed struct between the controller and the database.

Something like:

```rb
# obtain an instance of RecipeSearchParamsContract
def contract
  @contract ||= SomeValidationContract.new
end

# obtain an instance of a coercing struct
def input
  MyStruct.new(params)
end

def query
  MyQuery.new
end

def your_action
  if contract.call(params).success?
    render query.call(input)
  end
end
```

So you are completely separating all the concerns. Good libraries to base your code on are `dry-validator` and `dry-struct`, with which you can generate a contract in the following way:

```rb
class SearchParamsContract < Dry::Validation::Contract
  params do
    optional(:sort).hash(max_size?: 1) do
      optional(:rate).value(included_in?: %w[asc desc])
      optional(:created_at).value(included_in?: %w[asc desc])
      optional(:total_time).value(included_in?: %w[asc desc])
    end
    optional(:page).value(:integer)
    optional(:term).filled(:string)
  end
end
```

Using this, the coerced and validated struct is availble in the result itself, so you can chain all together and use structural pattern matching to get awesome and very ruby code (no rails extra stuff)

```rb
def search
  case contract.call(params)
  in Success(input)
    @recipes = query.call(input)
  else
    render :error
  end
end
```